# C function with parameter types declared after parameters?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring function parameters after function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151402/declaring-function-parameters-after-function-name)
>   [C function syntax, parameter types declared after parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585390/c-function-syntax-parameter-types-declared-after-parameter-list)

I'm fairly new to C and was mucking around with timing and came across the following function.  I can get it to work by passing pointers to it.  I don't really understand whats happening here though. What does the third line do and how is the second line even legal?

```
int 
timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
     struct timeval *result, *x, *y;
{
  ... (function code here)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very old C syntax for function declaration. It is not recommended to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efx873ys.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Seems like some old C code. (Kernighan & Ritchie, according to the other answers.)

This defines the order of the arguments:

```
timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
```

This defines their types:

```
 struct timeval *result, *x, *y;
```

It's the same as:

```
int timeval_subtract (struct timeval *result,
                      struct timeval *x,
                      struct timeval *y)
{
    // ...
}
```

(Those `struct`s are redundant in C++, and the newest version of C, IIRC.)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like pretty ancient C, like K&R C or something... I do not think that's legal ANSI C.